# Drawer layout color not changing

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer

Tried to change the navigation drawer color to colorPrimary but the drawer layout color is not changing even though it is set to colorPrimary.It shows on Android Studio but on actual run it is set to white.!

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:padding="0dp"
android:paddingBottom="0dp"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:itemIconTint="@android:color/background_light"
    app:itemTextColor="@android:color/background_light"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer">

</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**check this one**

[image]

Comment: This information is not complete to understand the issue, If you can your layout xml, then it would be easy to identify issue.

Comment: share your color.xml or drawer_layout.xml so we can go through what exactly going on

Comment: please add code what you have done so far.

Comment: show your result screenshot

Comment: Yeh code added ,,

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/to2NL.jpg

Comment: for `NavigationView` set `android:background="@color/yourColor"`

Comment: android:background="@color/yourColor" worked thankyou @Redman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code..

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="start"
app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_drawer_header"
app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer"
android:background="@color/color_navigation_list_background"
app:itemIconTint="@color/color_selector_navigation_item"
app:itemTextColor="@color/color_selector_navigation_item"/>
```

Comment: the color of navigation menu changes but the background of drawer layout remains white

Comment: android:background="@color/colorAccent"